# If I sign in to Humble Bundle monthly now, will I get this month's bundle or the next month's bundle?

Tags: pc, humble-bundle

Humblebundle (humblebundle.com) is currently running a promotion that they will provide Sid Meier's Civilization VI as part of February's bundle if I opt into their Monthly program. But there seems to  be no mention in the site about a way to get this month's bundle.

Which bundle will I get if I sign up now? January's bundle or February's bundle?

Comment: You can't - that's the bargain: You pay Humble in advance, they give you a bunch of games next month (in addition to the headline game which they give you now - ie. Civ 6). The list of this and previous month's bundle content is just advertisement.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's how their business works. May be, they do it to avoid people doing hit-and-run? Or may be to avoid conventional sales of games getting affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Purchasing humble monthly now (January 5th, 2018) will get you the February 2018 monthly bundle

The way that humble bundle markets their monthly bundle is somewhat unclear.
There are two sets of games in each monthly bundle: a publicized set that you get to "play now" as soon as you pay for the bundle, and a secret set that is revealed at the 5th of the next month. The secret set of games is revealed right after that month's bundle stops being sold.

The way the bundles are named corresponds with the date that the entire bundle is available, so the January 2018 bundle (which unlocked on January 5th, 2018), was on sale for most of December as well as from January 1st through January 4th. The bundle that you buy from January 5th until February 4th is the February bundle.

To sum up: If you want the Humble Monthly bundle for January 2018, you will need to go back in time and sign up in the past. If you want the humble monthly bundle for February 2018, you should sign up now. After signing up, you will get to play the publicized games, but the secret games in the February 2018 bundle will not be revealed until February 5th, 2018.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I got it now! By the way, I am going for the Feb bundle right now!

Comment: It's a shame they sell it this way... it's one of the reasons I won't buy a Humble Monthly bundle.

Comment: @Powerlord yeah I buy it based on if the revealed game is worth it to me

Comment: I bought it once for Dark Souls 2:SotFS, for $12.  That alone was worth it.  Then the rest of the games were very meh, so I unsubscribed.  I also got an extra 10% off for two other games I bought that month, so it worked out well that month.